# Cloudstack- Unable to delete secondary storage

Tags: mysql, rhel, kvm, apache-cloudstack

I am working on a model of cloudstack framework to analyse the feasibility of Cloudstack with my organization's product.

I was trying to delete secondary storage from the cloudstack's UI but it was failing due to the error "Cannot delete image store with active templates backup!". I later went through several blogs on Internet for this and did several modification in the mysql database (in tables such as template_host_ref, vm_template, etc) without taking any prior backup of the database.

Is there any default database backup imported during installation of cloudstack which can help me to restore modified database? I mean, which could lead to restore initial configuration. 
If not then what is the possible solution to get back to the initial state?
Please suggest as I am very new in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How was this problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems reasonable.  CloudStack should stop you from deleting secondary storage if the zone is in use.  Secondary storage holds all template disk images including system VMs that CloudStack uses to operate the zone.  If the zone is enabled, deleting secondary storage would cause it to fail.  Therefore, CloudStack should stop you from deleting secondary storage.

For non-production deployments of CloudStack, you are probably better off re-installing the system.  Note that for certain hypervisor types, CloudStack will delete existing VMs.

Direct further questions to the 'users' group on the [apache cloudstack mailing list](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).